# How sensitive is QFT calculation to (in)finiteness of our universe

Tags: quantum-field-theory, observable-universe

We do not yet know whether our universe is finite or infinite - actually we may never know because we only see observable parts of our universe.

Typical QFT calculations are done assuming that our universe is infinite - as Hamiltonian is integrated over infinite flat space. How sensitive is Hamiltonian (especially) and QFT calculations to truncating spacetime theory to a finite and observable part of universe? And of course ignore gravitational effects and issue of quantum gravity.

Comment: The spectrum of the momentum becomes discrete for a universe of finite size.

Comment: Elaborating a bit: since there would be a maximum wavelength, there would also be a minimum momentum. The IR divergences that plague QFT after renormalization would cease to exist. Interestingly, this might mean that Bremsstrahlung radiation would be heavily suppressed - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_divergence.

Comment: Nothing is infinite. Not even our idea of infinity.

Comment: QFT needs infrared regularization. Infinite universe is restored in the limit when the regularizer goes to zero. This limit has to be smooth, otherwise the (renormalized) theory wouldn’t exist. So no, perturbative QFT is not sensitive to finiteness of our Universe. However, on the nonperturbative level we can’t claim this anymore. Eg spontaneous symmetry breaking doesn’t happen in the Universe of the finite size. I am unsure of how physical this result is though.